# Setting limits.conf file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

If we set the `softlimit` and `hardlimit` of `nproc` in `limits.conf` file of OS user to `unlimited`, is there any possible chance that we may not be able to login via oraprod/root user?

Provided below is the syntax in `limits.conf` file located at `/etc/security/limits.conf` :

```
oraprod soft nproc unlimited
oraprod hard nproc unlimited
```

If not, what are the possible consequences of such a change?

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding problem with login for `oraprod`/`root` user

   `nproc` is used for defining the maximum number of processes ( includes number of lightweight threads ) that are available to a user. It has nothing to do with login ability of user. However as mentioned later ( look below ), if system resources are hogged up, it can lead to system being not responsive so that could affect the login ability of users.
2. Regarding other possible consequences

   Setting `nproc` hard-limit to unlimited makes the system vulnerable to threats such as a fork-bomb which can hog up your system resources and cause it to crash.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is there any possibility that after system reboot the parameter soft and hard changes to unlimited automatically???

Comment: I don't think the parameters will change automatically upon reboot.

Comment: We had an unusual situation in oracle cloud in one virtual machine, where the vm went running after system reboot but the system crashes when we are logging via opc user. On further investigation we found both parameters of soft and hard limits were unlimited.

Comment: "vm went running after system reboot" - it ran smoothly as it was expected or it was already running? Also just `oraprod` user has such soft and hard limits or you have made changes for other users too? Also changes in `limits.conf` are only applied in new sessions, not those already running.

Comment: Basically we had a situation where we were unable to login via non root user. it was giving an message "su: /bin/bash: Resource temporarily unavailable". The average load was too high for the server. So we changed the limits.conf file soft parameter to a greater value, which resolved the issue. After checking the application logs we reverted back the changes in limits.conf file, but for the unusual high load we need to reboot the server. The box showed running in cloud console, but we the VM crashed when we gave the passphrase for opc.

Comment: We made changes to oraprod user only. We made changes in the running sessions. Under further inspection we found that after reboot the limits.conf file parameter for both soft and hard has changed to unlimited. Is this the primary reason for the crash??

Comment: Seems to be. Just to be sure try running `ps | gawk '{count[$NF]++}END{for(j in count) print ""count[j]":",j}'|sort -rn|head -n20 `. It will give you a count of the processes running currently. Also look into `.bash_profile` or `.profile` file in `oraprod` home directory. `ulimit` values can be set using those too.